# How do I design a Strategy Pattern Class in C++ based on an UML Diagram?

Tags: c++, oop, strategy-pattern

I'm designing a strategy pattern based on the following diagram:

[image: UML Diagram]

I have to base the entire program on two things: the contents of the main function, and the Sale function getTotal() - which I was provided with;

Here's what I managed to write so far:

```
class Product {
private:
    int code;
    string type;
    string description;
    int price;

public:
    Product(int code, string type, string description, int price): code{code}, type{type}, description{description}, price{price}{}

    int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
};

class SaleItem {
private:
    Product product;
public:
    int quantity;

    Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
};

class Sale {

public:
    SaleItem s;
    Sale(SaleItem s) : s{ s }{}
    vector<SaleItem> items;
    void additem(int n, Product p) {
        items.push_back(s(n,p));
    }

    double getTotal();
};

class DiscountPolicy {
public:
    virtual double getDiscount(const Sale* s, SaleItem si) = 0;
};

class CreditCardDiscount : public DiscountPolicy {
public:
    virtual double getDiscount(const Sale* s, SaleItem si) {
        return si.getQuantity() * si.getProduct().getPrice() * 0.02;
    }
};

class NoDiscount : public DiscountPolicy {
public:
    virtual double getDiscount(const Sale* s, SaleItem si) {
        return si.getQuantity() * si.getProduct().getPrice() * 0.00;
    }
};

double Sale::getTotal() {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        SaleItem sIt = items[i];
        double price = sIt.getQuantity() * sIt.getProduct().getPrice();
        //apply discount
        price -= discountPolicy->getDiscount(this, sIt);
        total += price;
    }
    return total;
}



    int main() {


        Sale s(new NoDiscount());
        Product p1(1, "Apple", "food", 2.0);
        Product p2(1, "TV", "electronics", 2000.0);
        s.addItem(3, p1);
        s.addItem(1, p2);
        assert(s.getTotal() == 2006);
        Sale s2(new CreditCardDiscount());
        s2.addItem(3, p1);
        s2.addItem(1, p2);
        //total with discount for card
        assert(s2.getTotal() == 1965.88);

    }
```

I'm currently encountering two issues:

1. I can't wrap my head around designing the Sale class so that "Sale s(new NoDiscount());" and "        Sale s2(new CreditCardDiscount());", from the main class, make sense.
2. I'm fairly certain there should be some code where the //apply discount comment is found in the getTotal() function, but I'm not sure how to implement it so that "price -= discountPolicy->getDiscount(this, sIt);" works.

The rest of the program should be implemented correctly, since I've seen similar designs, it's mainly the Sale function that I don't understand.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't know about the C++ program. However, there are some issues with the UML diagram: The multiplicity of `SaleItem`  at the `describes` association must be `0..*` (otherwise each product could only be sold once). The name of the abstract strategy class `DiscountPolicy` should be in italics, not in guillemets. As it is shown now, it would be an anonymous class, stereotyped with `DiscountPolicy`. And the concrete strategies should overwrite `getDiscount()`.

Comment: I've noticed that too - assumed it was a typo, 0..* makes sense the most in this scenario.